# Determination of the number of weeks

Tags: python

I have a today date and the date (for example, 2010-06-25). So,

```
from datetime import datetime, time, date
today = date.today()
year_past = 2010
past = datetime.strptime('25-06-'+str(year_past), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Then I need to find the number of weeks from past to now-date (int). Just explain me, I do this through timedelta and it doesnt work. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
delta = today - date(2010,6,25)
delta.days / 7
# out: 138
```